# Fabric Operations Console with Kubernetes Cluster on GKE Autopilot

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've been working on a Hyperledger Fabric based project that requires a console for viewing transactions carried out in the network. I tried using Fabric Operations Console ( https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-operations-console) .

I've converted the Docker Compose file to Kubernetes deployments, successfully deployed proxies for orderers and peers, and established connections using connection-profiles. However, I'm encountering issues:

```
Admin User Enrollment:
    CA is running, but I'm unable to enroll the admin user. The UI displays the error: "The certificate could not be generated. NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
```

[The error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GXgN.png)

When I view the /healthz route for my peers , it shows this error. But the peers are working just fine.

```
Docker Daemon Connectivity:
    When checking the operations URL, I'm encountering the error: "failed to ping to Docker daemon: Get 'http://unix.sock/_ping': dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory."
```

Fabric Console Pod Logs:

```
    The fabric console pod logs indicate the error: "error: [status_req yqu] unable to reach destination. error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 34.118.234.235:9443."
```

Environment details:

```
Kubernetes: GKE Autopilot Cluster
```

I'm seeking assistance from the community, especially from those who have experience with Kubernetes integration. Any insights or guidance on troubleshooting these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Also , Please suggest if there is any better tool to visualize the transactions being carried out in the hyperledger network . The functional requirement here is to have a ui that maintains a log of all the operations in the network .

Thank you in advance!